# How to check if arguments are legit?

Tags: bash

I have to write a bash script which will count all the commands in a text file. Arguments to a script are `-p`, `-n num`, and a file. This means that commands like:

```
script.sh -n 3 -p file.txt
script -p -n 3 file.txt
```

and similar are all legit.

However, I have to echo an error for any commands that are not similar to this: `script.sh -n -k file.txt` for example.

Here is a [link to my code](http://pastebin.com/nPict57R).

I managed to make it work, but it is way too long and redundant. Is there a way I can do this in a short way?

Comment: Shorter than what, exactly? Please show what you have.

Comment: Are you using the `getopts` builtin or GNU `getopt` already?

Comment: okay, here it is. i figured out it doesn't work 100% right-script.sh -n 3 -k will  work with no problems, eventhough -k isn't a legit command.
pastebin.com/nPict57R

Comment: I've posted some info about the two standard tools. You may want to give them a try, they can save you a lot of time. Your current code will be difficult to read even for you after some time has passed.

Comment: @rok, you have be very specific about what is "legit". Exactly which options are allowed? Which of them take arguments? Which are mandatory? Without specific requirements, how are you supposed to get what you want?

Comment: You are right, but I'm actually quite new to bash and I'm not even sure if I'm allowed to use the code you posted (this is my homework, I did 95% of it, I just need to redo this part of the code.

Comment: glenn, if I want to "call" my script it has to look like this: script.sh -n +number -p file.txt. file.txt must be the last argumen, however, -n and -p can be switched.
btw, -p does smething with pipes and -n is a number which is used in a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest another snippet that is a lot simpler to read than yours, because it exactly depicts the only two valid cases you specified in your comment:

> If I want to "call" my script it has to look like this: `script.sh -n +number -p file.txt`. `file.txt` must be the last argument, however, `-n` and `-p` can be switched.

So the cases are (`$0` to `$4`):

- `script.sh` `-n` `+number` `-p` `file.txt`
- `script.sh` `-p` `-n` `+number` `file.txt`

It uses only `if` and Bash's logical operators:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! { [[ "$1" = "-n" ]] && [[ "$2" =~ ^-[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ "$3" = "-p" ]] && [[ "$4" =~ ".txt"$ ]] ; } &&
   ! { [[ "$2" = "-n" ]] && [[ "$3" =~ ^-[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ "$1" = "-p" ]] && [[ "$4" =~ ".txt"$ ]] ; }
then
    echo "Error" && exit 1
fi
```

Notes:

- The group (`{`, `}`) syntax expects a `;` at the end of its list.
- You have to use a regex to check for `*.txt`
- The number regex you gave will require the number to start with a `-`, while in your specification you say `+`.

Comment: Unfortunately, these 2 were just examples, and not only possible cases.
script.sh -n +number file.txt 
script.sh -p file.txt
are also valid

Comment: alright, I tried ehoing arguments, and it appears that in stat.sh -n 3 -p file.txt $0 = stat.sh -n, and not just stat.sh. any ideas why?

Comment: @RokDolinar: Well, with these two the others won't be hard to write, will they? And about your `$0` problem, that sounds unlikely, how exactly did you find that out?

Comment: Yeah I did, and it should be working, but this problem with arguments is still there. Well I thought it is strange my code isnt working so i decided to echo $1 $2 $3 $4 and there was no -n. So i tried with $0 and it echoed stat.sh -n. Strange, I know.

Comment: @RokDolinar: If you paste your whole script, I can have a quick look at that $0 thing.

Comment: @RokDolinar: Ah, the `-n` got interpreted as an option by `echo`. As I just noticed, `echo`does not even have the usual `--` switch to separate options from other arguments either. So you better use `printf` if your text may look like an option: `printf "%s %s %s %s %s\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"`

Comment: http://shrani.si/f/2Q/4w/1iexR4g1/oqwiwiwiw.png 
Okay here it is.. I double quoted everytime and it happened as you see in the picture.. first one is echo "$1", second one is echo "$2" and so on. It works for everything except for second arg. Im sorry for wasting your time, but this thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: @RokDolinar: Yes, sorry, disregard that, I've modified my comment, the quoting was not the problem.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b7htwexV Okay I did as you said with every possible solution that is legit, but it still doesnt work properly.. stat.sh -p -k will work, even tho -k isnt allowed

Comment: @RokDolinar: It is allowed, there is a line where you only check `-p`, you probably want to add another test for an empty `$2` there. I've got to go now. If you use `set -x` at the beginning Bash prints all statements that are actually executed. That can help with debugging if you need any more of that. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much man! I actually hard coded quite badly but it works. I checked for the number of args, and then did the if statements.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at one of the following standard commands:

- `getopts` is a Bash builtin. It is newer and simple to use, but does not support long options (`--option`).
- `getopt` is an external program which may involve a little more glue code. There are different implementations. `getopt` usually supports long options.

This is a small `getopts` example (modified one of the examples from this [external site](http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html)):

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=off
dir=

# iterate over each option with getopts:
while getopts fd: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
      f)  flag=on;;
      d)  dir="$OPTARG";;
      *)  echo >&2 "usage: $0 [-f] [-d directory] [file ...]"
      exit 1;;
    esac
done

# remove all positional pararmeters we already 
# handled from the command line:
shift $(( expr $OPTIND - 1 ))

# main part of your program, remaining arguments are now in
# $@ resp. $0, $1, ...
```

Comment: hmm i thought there is a simpler way to do it. there is what i've done so far : pastebin.com/nPict57R it work as it should, the only problem is that it doesnt echo an error when I do this (example): script.sh -n 3 -k file.txt, it looks like it only checks first argument

Comment: Do you really think your code is simpler? It is actually very hard to understand because it uses 10 conditionals, and all that because you are trying to manually take the order of arguments into account, something the standard tools do for you transparently and in a well-tested way.

Comment: I was trying to say it uses simpler commands (if statement, few ands and few ors).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, and I just saw that this is an assignment, so using standard tools will be less important to you than in a business environment. One more question... what do you mean with `$1 != *.txt` - the literal string `*.txt` or do you mean `*` to match all characters?

Comment: if the argument doesn't end with .txt, it echoes error.

Comment: @RokDolinar: OK I've added another answer that is both shorter and does not use any other syntax than yours. Hope that helps. Just remember that in a real-world application, you would almost always go for the standard tools, because it saves time and they are usually well-designed and well-tested.